Multi data source configuration with Spring Batch, Spring Data JPA, and Querydsl
I'd like to write a batch application with Spring Batch using ChunkOrientedTasklet where I should execute multiple update queries against two different data sources(logical databases in the same physical database instance in MySQL) in ItemProcessor.
Let's elaborate the situation I'm in in more detail.
In a same physical database instance,

database A

table a
table b


database B

table c



chunk size of the tasklet is 1, so I'd like to process 1 row of table 'a' at a time and execute multiple update queries against table 'a', 'b', 'c' all in one transaction.
I'd like to define Entity classes and 'JpaRepository's interfaces for each table('a', 'b', and 'c'), and execute update queries both with JpaRepository and Querydsl in implementation classes of QuerydslRepositorySupport. I'm going to use JpaPagingItemReader for reading rows of table 'a' with page size 20.
I've just tried to set two different groups of beans for DataSource, EntityManagerFactory, TransactionManager, TransactionTemplate, etc, and specify @EnableJpaRepositories annotation with those of each packages where each groups of Entities are located, EntityManagerFactory, and TransactionManager. But, I got an error while I execute update query in ItemProcessor against table 'b' of database 'A' in the subclass of QuerydslRepositorySupport even though I've set TransactionManager of the database 'A' while creating TaskletStep with StepBuilderFactory, which is in the same database 'A'. I didn't get any error while reading rows from table 'a' in both ItemReader and ItemProcessor(update query works well with JpaRepository.save(Entity), FYI).
The error was,
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1692)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAUpdateClause.execute(JPAUpdateClause.java:76)
    at com.ohouse.content.onedb.migration.batch.domain.monodb.service.PraiseService.batchUpdatePraisableIds(PraiseService.kt:30)
    at com.ohouse.content.onedb.migration.batch.domain.monodb.service.PraiseService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$95b5fefa.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 170 more

How should I configure to achieve this goal?
